# How to solve undefined reference to _imp__** while building a console application in DEV-CPP linked to a static library?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, gaul

**Background Information**
I'm trying to build the GAUL library according to this [Instructions](http://gaul.sourceforge.net/windows-DevCPP.html) .

**The Problem**
Well I have two static libraries in C, build by me in Dev-CPP Windows 7 64 bit, one referencing the other.

And to test those I created a Console Application which referenced them.

Well when I tried to compile this is the log I getting:

```
> Compiler: Default compiler  
> Building Makefile: "C:\Soft\GAUL\Makefile.win"  
> Executing  make...  
> make.exe -f  
> "C:\Soft\GAUL\Makefile.win" all  
> **gcc.exe ../gaul-devel-windows/examples/struggle.o  -o "struggle.exe" -L"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib" gaul-util.a gaul-devel.a**    
>   
> gaul-util.a(memory_util.o)(.text+0x2e):memory_util.c: undefined reference to '_imp__mem_chunk_new_real'  
> gaul-util.a(memory_util.o)(.text+0x6c):memory_util.c: undefined reference to '_imp__mem_chunk_free_real'  
> ...  
> gaul-devel.a(ga_core.o)(.text+0x101):ga_core.c: undefined reference to 'slink_free_all'   
> gaul-devel.a(ga_core.o)(.text+0x360):ga_core.c: undefined reference to 'mem_chunk_new_real'  
> ...  
> collect2: ld returned 1  
> exit status
> 
> make.exe: *** [struggle.exe] Error 1
> 
> Execution terminated
```

I **think** that it has something to do with the parameters being used in the `gcc` command.

**Actual Status**
I've tried:
- Copying the libraries to C:\Dev-Cpp\lib
- Using the whole address before the libraries names
- Using -l before the libaries names
- Not using `.a` after the names

Not successful results with any of those.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The latest version of Dev-C++ was released in 2005. It is an extremely antiquated compiler, please consider upgrading to a modern one.

Comment: I was using that one because that is the one mentioned in the tutorial I'm following. Do you have any compiler recomendations?

Comment: Yes, GNU GCC. If you plan to target *only* windows consider using Visual Studio with the Visual C++ compiler.

Comment: It looks like you're just trying to link 2 static libraries and an object file that you previously compiled from source, is that right?  Also, are you sure you didn't skip Step 4 in Part III of the instructions?

Comment: @jedwards exactly, that's what Im trying to do! Yes, I didn't skip it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the End as @ThiefMaster♦ said I used a newer builder in this case VC++ and it just worked!

Answer (score 0):

The order of the arguments for linker (ld) is important. If your build fails on the

```
gcc.exe ../gaul-devel-windows/examples/struggle.o  -o "struggle.exe" -L"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib" gaul-util.a gaul-devel.a
```

line, then try reversing the order of the last two files:

```
gcc.exe ../gaul-devel-windows/examples/struggle.o  -o "struggle.exe" -L"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib" gaul-devel.a gaul-util.a
```

Comment: "_imp__mem_chunk_new_real" is a function pointer symbol and "mem_chunk_new_real" is a function itself. What I mean is you're using both dynamic link library (gaul-util might use some .dll) and static link library (gaul-devel uses mem_chunk_new_real from some static library). Check your build process once again for the .a-files.